# Making a regular grammar for this language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

I'm trying to make a regular grammar for this language:

[image]

Where the alphabet is $ \Sigma $ = $\{a,b,c\}$

It seemed like it would go well with a right-linear grammar.  This may be disastrously wrong, but here's how I started:

$S \to aA$

$A \to aA | cB $

$B \to bC | C $

$C \to cD |$ $\lambda$

$D \to cC$

EDIT:
Corrected for errors. Added $D$ for regular grammar.

Comment: This grammar produces the language $a + acb^*(cc)^*$ rather than the intended $a^*ac(\lambda + b)(cc)^*$.

Comment: Now it's $ac + ab^*(cc)^*$. I suggest you go over the material again and see that you understand how grammars work.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you're asking us to make a grammar for you for that particular grammar, that's probably not very interesting to others, as it is only relevant to someone else who has the exact same language as you.